# Rank Function not limiting to first 5 ranked values Postgresql Windows Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, rank

I am trying to get the last previous five sessions data for a number of products. I am using the below query but it is not showing the first 5 only, its showing all sessions with a rank column. 
Could someone assist me to troubleshoot to filter and show the first 5 only?

```
Select 
sessionid, 
productid, 
processed_nos,
rank()
OVER (
    PARTITION BY productid
    ORDER BY sessionid Asc
    ROWS BETWEEN 5 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS per_session_rank
from stats_stable
```

Comment: And if you add ` limit 5` ?

Comment: Limit 5 shows the first 5 items from the 1st product only, I am hoping for 5 rows per product

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Derived Table to be able to filter the result of a RANK:

```
select *
from 
 (
   Select 
      sessionid, 
      productid, 
      processed_nos,
      rank()
      OVER (PARTITION BY productid
            ORDER BY sessionid Asc
           ) AS per_session_rank
   from stats_stable
 ) as dt
WHERE per_session_rank <= 5
```